# Algorithm analysis (big-O) for algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, notation, asymptotic-complexity

I'm trying to help a friend analyze the complexity of his algorithm but my understanding of Big-O notation is quite limited.

The code goes like this:

```
int SAMPLES = 2000;
int K_SAMPLES = 5000;

int i = 0; // initial index position    
while (i < SAMPLES)
{
    enumerate();                       // Complexity: O(SAMPLES)
    int neighbors = find_neighbors(i); // Complexity: O(1) 

    // Worst case scenario, neighbors is the same number of SAMPLES
    int f = 0;
    while (f < neighbors) // This loop is probably O(SAMPLES) as well.
    {
        int k = 0; // counter variable
        while (k < K_SAMPLES) // Not sure how to express the complexity of this loop.
        {                     // Worst case scenario K_SAMPLES might be bigger than SAMPLES. 

            // do something!

            k++;
        }
        f++;
    }

    i++;
}
```

There are 2 functions inside the code but I was able to identify their complexity since they are simple. However, I was unable to express the complexity of the inner `while` loop, but even after it is measured, I still need help to assemble all these complexities into a formula that represents the computational complexity of the algorithm.

I seriously need help on this matter. Thanks!

Comment: `while (i < neighbors)` won't this loop infinitely? `i` and `neighbors` are not modified.

Comment: What are the variables here? Is N the only variable? I'm guessing N represents the set of all neighbors. Do you assume SAMPLES and K_SAMPLES to be fixed? Because then they wont even matter when calculating the big-O.

Comment: True. Fixed the issue, thanks @nhahtdh

Comment: What is `n`?  Which of these inputs are variable?  You may need to express it in terms of multiple variables if, for example, `SAMPLES` and `K_SAMPLES` vary independently of one another.

Comment: I meant to write `O(SAMPLES)` and not `O(n)`. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: The issues were fixed. What do you guys think of the answers so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worst case analysis going from inner most loop to outer most ([with mild abuse of the "=" sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Equals_sign)):

```
->  O(K_SAMPLES)                    -- complexity of just the k-loop

->  neighbors * O(K_SAMPLES)         -- complexity of f-loop accounted for
 =  SAMPLES * O(K_SAMPLES)          -- since neighbors = SAMPLES in worst case
 =  O(SAMPLES * K_SAMPLES)

->  O(SAMPLES) + O(SAMPLES * K_SAMPLES)  -- adding complexity of enumerate()
 =  O(SAMPLES + SAMPLES * K_SAMPLES)
 =  O(SAMPLES * K_SAMPLES)
```

The `SAMPLES` term was dropped since `SAMPLES * K_SAMPLES` grows asymptotically faster. More formally,

```
When C >= 2, SAMPLES >= 1, K_SAMPLES >= 1 then

SAMPLES + SAMPLES * K_SAMPLES  <=  C(SAMPLES * K_SAMPLES)
SAMPLES * (K_SAMPLES + 1)  <=  SAMPLES * C * K_SAMPLES
K_SAMPLES + 1  <=  C * K_SAMPLES
```

For more info on big-O with multiple variables, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables). Continuing on with the last loop we have:

```
->  SAMPLES * O(SAMPLES * K_SAMPLES)    -- complexity of i-loop accounted for
 =  O(SAMPLES^2 * K_SAMPLES)
```

Note that depending on the average number returned by `find_neighbors(i)`, it can make the average big-O different.

Comment: +1 For abuse. Kidding aside, the answer looks good. I wish somebody else could evaluate it too so I can close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

O(neighbors * K_SAMPLES)

if neighbors << K then this is closer to linear in K_SAMPLES

If neighbors on order of K_SAMPLES this is quadratic in K_SAMPLES